# Angular Types of property 'fileType' are incompatible when using enum swagger values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

maybe I am missing something but I am getting error mentioned in thread name (or with more details on the end of this thread).

I am trying to do this:

```
   onAvatarChangeSubmit(): void {
    
        const fileUploadParams = {
          fileType: 'USER_AVATAR',
          body: {
            file: this.pictureBase64
          }
        };
    
        this.avatarFormFileUploadSubscription = this.fileControllerService.uploadFile$Response(fileUploadParams)
          .subscribe((response: StrictHttpResponse<FileUploadResponse>) => {
            console.log(response);
          });
    }
```

Which is pretty simple, I retrieve base64 coded image as a string, I pass a type of file I want to upload (its user avatar this time) and I post it to the backend, where image is processed (file is validated, stored in file system and linked to database entity. The UUID of entity is then returned).

I am using `fileControllerService.uploadFile$Response` method which is method generated by ng-openapi-gen https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-openapi-gen, which just loads OpenAPI 3 swagger YAML and generated a thin API layer (controller services, models, ...).

Generated method has this signature:

```
  /**
   * This method provides access to the full `HttpResponse`, allowing access to response headers.
   * To access only the response body, use `uploadFile()` instead.
   *
   * This method sends `application/json` and handles request body of type `application/json`.
   */
  uploadFile$Response(params?: {
    fileType?: 'USER_AVATAR' | 'UNKNOWN' | 'DELIVERY_LOGO' | 'PAYMENT_LOGO' | 'ITEM_PICTURE';
    body?: { 'file'?: Blob }
  }): Observable<StrictHttpResponse<FileUploadResponse>> {

    const rb = new RequestBuilder(this.rootUrl, FileControllerService.UploadFilePath, 'post');
    if (params) {
      rb.query('fileType', params.fileType, {});
      rb.body(params.body, 'application/json');
    }

    return this.http.request(rb.build({
      responseType: 'blob',
      accept: '*/*'
    })).pipe(
      filter((r: any) => r instanceof HttpResponse),
      map((r: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        return r as StrictHttpResponse<FileUploadResponse>;
      })
    );
  }
```

Method is generated correctly from my swagger API. There is a fileType request param which is enumerated on the backend side to decide how to handle specific type of image.

I assume that `|` symbol means I can pass one of 5 following strings (UNKNOWN, USER_AVATAR, ...).
But when I do that (see onAvatarChangeSubmit method), where i pass a USER_AVATAR string, I get an error which is probably from typescript compilation.

```
Failed to compile.

src/app/account/account-general/account-general.component.ts:78:92 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ fileType: string; body: { file: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ fileType?: "USER_AVATAR" | "UNKNOWN" | "DELIVERY_LOGO" | "PAYMENT_LOGO" | "ITEM_PICTURE"; body?: { file?: Blob; }; }'.
  Types of property 'fileType' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"USER_AVATAR" | "UNKNOWN" | "DELIVERY_LOGO" | "PAYMENT_LOGO" | "ITEM_PICTURE"'.

78     this.avatarFormFileUploadSubscription = this.fileControllerService.uploadFile$Response(fileUploadParams)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, it's typescript complaining about incompatible type assignment
And also yes, `|` means you can use any of these types, in this case, these [Literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html)

but by creating this object

```
       const fileUploadParams = {
          fileType: 'USER_AVATAR',
          body: {
            file: this.pictureBase64
          }
        };
```

without defining any type, these values by default considered as strings, because they are already strings! and in this case you are trying to assign a string to a another custom type

**How to fix it?**
there're different ways to solve this, for example:

1. Pass the parameter object directly to the function call, without creating a new object:

```
        this.avatarFormFileUploadSubscription = 
          this.fileControllerService.uploadFile$Response({
            fileType: 'USER_AVATAR',
            body: {
              file: this.pictureBase64
            }
          })
          .subscribe((response: StrictHttpResponse<FileUploadResponse>) => {
            console.log(response);
          });
```

2. Or, use the same type for your created object:

```
       const fileUploadParams: {
         fileType: 'USER_AVATAR';
         body: { file: Blob }
       } = {
          fileType: 'USER_AVATAR',
          body: {
            file: this.pictureBase64
          }
        };
```